# How to use regular Javascript variables in Expressjs or Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way i can export variables from regular javascript to be used in expressjs?

i have tried using 'exports' but it didn't work.

for example in regular js file

```
var search ='hello';
exports= search;
```

then in express file

```
var search= require("./file.js");
console.log(search);
```

all i get in the console is '{}'.

What i want is for the variable 'search' to work in my express file as well. is there a way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [exports shortcut](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut) in the docs:

> The `exports` variable is available within a module's file-level scope, and is assigned the value of `module.exports` before the module is evaluated.

But it also says that:

> However, be aware that like any variable, if a new value is assigned to `exports`, it is no longer bound to `module.exports`.

So when you do `exports= search`, it's not exported, only available in the module. To make it work, you just need to change it to `module.exports = search`.

Related: [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Here is the proper way of doing it:

**Wrong way**

```
var search ='hello';
exports= search;
```

**Correct way**

```
var search = 'hello';
exports.search = search;
```

**To call it**

```
var { search } = require('./file.js')
console.log(search)
```

I hope my answer was clear and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! To export a variable in **file1**:

```
var search = 'hello'
export search

// OR

export var search = 'hello'
```

To import it in **file2**:

```
import * as someName from './file1'
someName.search

// OR

var someName = require('./file1')
someName.search
```

Read more here: https://javascript.info/import-export